# using data column as "axis" in table with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm new to pgfplots/pgfplotstable and got the following problem.
I got a datafile like the following I use for plotting with pgfplots:

```
P1 P2 Value
1 1 0.00000000000e+00
1 2 1.00000000000e-02
1 3 0.00000000000e+00

2 1 1.00000000000e-02
2 2 1.00000000000e-02
2 3 3.00000000000e-02
```

I can plot this using pgfplots:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
height=15cm,
width=\textwidth%,
]
\addplot3[surf] table {../../results/testdatafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Now I would like to add a table presenting the data like this:

```
P2/P1 1                 2
1     0.00000000000e+00 1.00000000000e-02
2     1.00000000000e-02 1.00000000000e-02
3     0.00000000000e+00 3.00000000000e-02
```

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the stringstrings package could be used to parse/extract terms from your input file, and then reassemble them as you wish.  When I get to a system with LaTeX, I may follow up with an example (in a few days).  The ease with which that can be done will depend on how predictable your datasets are.

Comment: p.s.  I think your "would like" table has a typo in it (last row, last column should be 3...)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks for your answer, yes it's a typo I will correct it, I will have a look at stringstrings package and will post it here if I could achieve what I'm trying to.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the stringstrings \getargs command to grab/parse the data.  Then I wrote a \readArray command to save it.  Then I could recall the data into a tabular array from both tables.  I could either invoke it using the saved variable names (1st table) or using the \Arrayij command (2nd table)

Currently, stringstrings array size is limited to a 500 character string, but that can be increased by modifying the following parameter in stringstrings.sty

\def\@MAXSTRINGSIZE{500}

I do not know how slow it will be for larger tables.  stringstrings can be very slow, depending on the action.

For my simple example, I did not need to do that.  Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\readArray[3]{
  \setcounter{index}{0}
  \setcounter{row}{1}
  \setcounter{col}{0}
  \getargs{#1}
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{index}{1}
%    \arabic{index}:~
    \addtocounter{col}{1}
    \ifthenelse{\value{col} > #3}
      {\addtocounter{row}{1}
       \addtocounter{col}{-#3}}
      {}
%    \arabic{row}-\arabic{col}\\
    \expandafter\edef\csname#2X\roman{row}X\roman{col}\endcsname%
      {\expandafter\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}
  }
}

\newcommand\Arrayij[3]{%
  \setcounter{row}{#2}
  \setcounter{col}{#3}
  \csname#1X\roman{row}X\roman{col}\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

\def\dataA{
.15 12 13 14
.20 22 23 24
.25 32 33 Ending
}
\def\dataB{
.15 x12 x13 x14
.20 z22 x23 x24
.25 x32 x33 xEnding
}

\readArray{\dataA}{arA}{4}
\readArray{\dataB}{arB}{4}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Value & Data A & Data B\\
      & col3   & col3\\
\hline
\arAXiXi   & \arAXiXiii   & \arBXiXiii   \\
\arAXiiXi  & \arAXiiXiii  & \arBXiiXiii  \\
\arAXiiiXi & \arAXiiiXiii & \arBXiiiXiii \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1em}
\ldots or you can use the $\backslash$Arrayij command to invoke the
data

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Value & Data A & Data B\\
      & col4   & col4\\
\hline
\Arrayij{arA}{1}{1} & \Arrayij{arA}{1}{4} & \Arrayij{arB}{1}{4} \\
\Arrayij{arA}{2}{1} & \Arrayij{arA}{2}{4} & \Arrayij{arB}{2}{4} \\
\Arrayij{arA}{2}{1} & \Arrayij{arA}{3}{4} & \Arrayij{arB}{3}{4} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @soriak FYI, I've developed a faster version of \getargs found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100865/parsing-a-as-part-of-an-improved-getargs-command, as long as you don't use a \$ in your datasets

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had to do other stuff the last week. I will take a look now and give feedback, afterwards

Comment: @soriak Still better version of getargs and alternative versions proposed by others at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101604/parsing-strings-containing-diacritical-marks-macros

Comment: I added an output to my data generation which outputs the data in needed format. Since your version as well as all other that I found, need manual access to the entries in the matrix, it is not suitable for matrices with varying sizes. Thanks anyway?

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work, but I'm not sure of your meaning "manual access".  The `\readArray` takes as its second argument a specified but arbitrary array width, and reads a dataset of arbitrary array height.  Ar you saying you want what amounts to a do loop on the tabular row creation?