# Parsing a \$ as part of an improved \getargs command

Tags: arrays, parsing

As the author of `stringstrings`, I am acutely aware of its slowness.  For small tasks, that slowness can be annoying.  For larger tasks, it can be prohibitive.

Recently, in [using data column as "axis" in table with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100557/using-data-column-as-axis-in-table-with-pgfplotstable/100730#100730), I proposed a solution, using the `\getargs` command (of the `stringstrings` package) as part of the solution on how to read and store a 2-D array for future use (`\getargs` will parse an argument into individual words).  That solution envisioned a syntax such as

```
\readArray{\dataA}{arA}{4}
\readArray{\dataB}{arB}{4}
```

for reading lists of data into, for example, 4 columns, and identifying the arrays by unique identifiers such as arA, arB, etc., so that, when later building a tabular, one could use

```
\Arrayij{arA}{1}{1} & \Arrayij{arA}{1}{4} & \Arrayij{arB}{1}{4} to call back various elements of the input arrays.  I could immediately see that these datasets could become large, and I feared the `\getargs` command developed for `stringstrings` would be too slow for processing a large array.
```

So I tried to rewrite a fast version of `\getargs` (call it`\getargsFAST`), from a completely different angle, using a streamlined recursion, rather than the exhaustive `\if\else\fi` approach that allows `stringsstrings` to handle extended character sets.  I understand and accept that the two versions will not act exactly alike.  I figured that an array of data (for which `\getargsFAST` is designed) would contain mostly numbers, maybe some words (for units or cases) and (for financial folks) the dollar sign `\$`.  And it's the dollar sign that is confounding me at present.

I've tried various things, but can't get `\getargsFAST` to process `\$` as part of the input data.  Is there an fix apparent to those well versed in lower-level TeX, which I am not.

Here is the routine, as part of an example, and its output.  Note: I did not use `\$` in the input, because then I wouldn't have any output to post for you.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifnextok}

\makeatletter
\def\stringend{$}
\newcounter{arg@index}
\def\getargsFAST#1{\edef\argi{}\setcounter{arg@index}{1}%
                   \expandafter\parse@Block#1\stringend}
\def\parse@Block{\IfNextToken\stringend%
  {\edef\narg{\arabic{arg@index}}\@gobble}%
  {\IfNextToken\@sptoken{\addtocounter{arg@index}{1}%
   \expandafter\edef\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname{}%
   \add@to{\parse@Block}}%
  {\add@to{\parse@Block}}}}

 \def\add@to#1#2{\expandafter\edef\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname%
                   {\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname#2}#1}
\makeatother

\parskip 0.9ex \parindent 0in
\begin{document}

Test of getargsFAST (fast alternative to getargs of stringstrings package):

\def\myarg{This is a ~~test of   the emergency $x_i^2\alpha$ broadcast system}

Original argument:\par
\verb,This is a ~~test of   the emergency $x_i^2\alpha$ broadcast system,

\getargsFAST{\myarg}

Number of args is \narg, given as follows:\par
\argi \par
\argii \par
\argiii \par
\argiv \par
\argv \par
\argvi \par
\argvii \par
\argviii \par
\argix \par
\argx \par

Differences from getargs are probably numerous.  Here are some: hard
spaces are retained by FAST version only; FAST version has no built-in
argument size limit; FAST version chokes on the \verb,\$, character.

Like getargs, getargsFAST can process only a very limited set of math
tokens.  Obviously, \verb,#,, without a backslash, causes result to
choke.

Unlike getargs, getargsFAST provides no workarounds for processing
characters that cannot be put into an edef, such as \dag, \ddag, \P, \d
x, \t x, \b x, \copyright, as well as (in OT1 encoding) \_, \{, \}, \S,
\c x, and \pounds.

Other characters that will confound getargsFAST include the
\verb,&, (when entered without the backslash), and most of the
diacritical markings.

I will probably add this command to the stringstrings package when play
testing is complete.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special about `\$` here, just that you should never apply `\edef` to arbitrary user supplied input in LaTeX. It is only safe to use that if the tokens involved are under your control. Using `\protected@edef` things work out as I assume you intended.

```
\def\parse@Block{\IfNextToken\stringend%
  {\edef\narg{\arabic{arg@index}}\@gobble}%
  {\IfNextToken\@sptoken{\addtocounter{arg@index}{1}%
   \expandafter\def\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname{}%
   \add@to{\parse@Block}}%
  {\add@to{\parse@Block}}}}

 \def\add@to#1#2{\expandafter\protected@edef\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname%
                   {\csname arg\roman{arg@index}\endcsname#2}#1}
```

Comment: Furthermore, your approach allows the routine to operate on a large assortment of tokens that previously didn't work, some of which are mentioned in my output.  Not that I'm looking forward to it, but your answer really indicates a needed rewrite of stringstrings.